# Equivalent of CSS box-sizing in javafx

Tags: css, javafx

I'm building a JavaFX application. While playing with CSS I couldn't find an equivalent to **box-sizing** property like in ordinary CSS; the point is that I don't want the border to take space from outside of the shape I want it to be included in it's total width.

I used background insets and it worked as expected but its a bit tedious when changing the width of a border dynamically (the insets of the inner background in this case). Is there a way to avoid that?

- I'm using JavaFX 11.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Too late to the party, but there is no equivalent to this property.

Here is a link to the official CSS references of JavaFX: https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html

In the topic "Limitations" is explained, thatt the JavaFX CSS parser is not a full featured CSS parser.